# hide folder using .htaccess with subfolders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to figure out this for a while but no success-

I have this site structure `http://example.com/catalog/current/sub-folders/..`
The result should hide the folder "current" so that the paths look like `http://example.com/catalog/sub-folders/`

This is what I have so far-

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+current/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^current/)^(.*)$ /current/$1 [L,NC]
```

when I place this .htaccess to the root and go to `http://example.com/catalog/sub-folders/`, it try to look for `/current/catalog/sub-folders/`

Any help to approach this problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(catalog)/current/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(catalog)/((?!current/).*)$ $1/current/$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Tried this but does not seem to do anything

Comment: What URL did you try to test and what is location of this .htaccess? Are there more rules?

Comment: I put the .htaccess at the root of the server "/" No there are not other rules. The url I tried is localhost/catalog/current/test-1/

Comment: this works. thank you so much!! One last question- how can this be modified so that path like localhost/catalog/current/ or simply localhost/catalog/ also rewrites to whats inside "current"?

Comment: thanks for the updates. I tried that and it shows the contents of /catalog when I use localhost/catalog/current/  or  localhost/catalog/  but not what is in 'current'.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the last rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^hsc-bulletin/)^(.*)$ /current/$1 [L,NC]
```

This instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/current/
RewriteRule ^(?!hsc-bulletin/)(.*)$ /current/$1 [L,NC]
```